# Need average value PHP, Jquery, Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I've made a star rating system, using PHP, and Jquery. After i have stored my votes in a database im trying to print the average rate. The problem is the average value that gets printed its for all the items that im rating, not just the specifik one that im rating

This is my jquery code:

```
function rate(id, vote) {
    console.log(id, vote);
    $.post("rated.php", 
            { id: id, vote: vote }, function(data){
                console.log(data);
                $( ".totalrating") .html( data );
    });

};
```

And this is my php:

```
    $sql = "UPDATE images 
    SET votes = votes+1, tot_rating = tot_rating+$vote
    WHERE id ='$id' ";

    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die("Fel vid SQL query");


    $sql2 = "SELECT * from images WHERE id=$id";
    $result1 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql2) or die ("Fel vid SQL query");

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)) {
        $votes = $row['votes']; 
    }

    $sql3 = "SELECT * from images WHERE id=$id";
    $result2 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql3) or die ("Fel vid SQL query");

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)) {
        $sum = $row['tot_rating']; 
    }

    $avg = $sum / $votes;

    $avg1decimals = number_format($avg, 1);

    echo $avg1decimals;



} else {

}
```

Comment: why are you doing 2 selects with the same query?

Comment: I can't see where `$vote` and `$id` come from, but this looks like it might have SQL injection vulns in it (and, sadly, the two answers below have not pointed this out).

Answer (score 0):

Try a single select query:

```
 $sql = "UPDATE images 
    SET votes = votes+1, tot_rating = tot_rating+$vote
    WHERE id ='$id' ";

    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die("Fel vid SQL query");


    $sql2 = "SELECT * from images WHERE id=$id";
    $result1 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql2) or die ("Fel vid SQL query");

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)) {
       $avg = $row['tot_rating'] / $row['votes'];

       $avg1decimals = number_format($avg, 1);

       echo $avg1decimals;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one : Make sure ID is primary key in your table

```
$sql = "UPDATE images 
SET votes = votes+1, tot_rating = tot_rating+".$vote."
 WHERE id =".$id;
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die("Fel vid SQL query");

$sql = "SELECT * from images WHERE id=".$id."Limit 1";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql2) or die ("Fel vid SQL query");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
$votes = $row['votes']; 
$sum = $row['tot_rating'];
}

$avg = $sum / $votes;
$avg1decimals = number_format($avg, 1);

echo $avg1decimals;
```